# Customize text_area Ruby on rails to Materialize css

Tags: css, text, ruby-on-rails-5, materialize, label

Im trying to customise the "<%= f.text_area :content %>" in rails 5.0.

To a text_area that materialize has like this one

```
 <div class="row">
    <form class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">mode_edit</i>
          <textarea id="icon_prefix2" class="materialize-textarea"></textarea>
          <label for="icon_prefix2">First Name</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

The problem is that I tried to figure it out on how to insert the default text_area that I have in to this one, erasing the ugly box the I have to type a text. (I'm a bit fancy)

This is my form:

```
<%= form_for(@micropost, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

    <%= f.text_area :content %> >>>>>>#This is the one I want to change

  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "waves-effect waves-light btn green accent-3 z-depth-4" %>
  <span class="picture">
    <%= f.file_field :picture, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

---

This is what I tried:

```
<div class="row">
    <form class="col s12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">mode_edit</i>
          <textarea id="icon_prefix2" class="materialize-textarea"><%= f.text_area :content %></textarea>
          <label for="icon_prefix2">First Name</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

But i'm unlucky to make it work, and  I tried many other ways that I haven't figure out how to customise this feature to my app.

I spend to much time figuring out on how to erase that box and put a single fancy line style materialize way.
I will appreciate too much you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the problem you have?, you just need to add the corresponding class:

```
<%= f.text_area :content id: 'icon_prefix2', class: 'materialize-textarea' %>
```

Comment: Well I wasen't able to add a style to the ugly box, Im a newbie so, It might be strange that I was asking that, the thing is that  I was forgeting the id: option in order to customise the text_area for rails! But yeah It did work so thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome @kenSanchez, if you have doubts on what are the valid options for the helpers you're using you can take a look to its definition, mostly [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html).